Difference between generator expression and tuple expression
I have 2 statements
# Generator expression
squares_gen = (x**2 for x in range(10))

# Tuple comprehension
squares_tuple = (x**2 for x in range(10))

How does Python understand that the 1st statement is generator and the 2nd one is a tuple?
# Generator expression
squares_gen = (x**2 for x in range(10))

# Tuple comprehension
squares_tuple = (x**2 for x in range(10))

for square in squares_gen:
    print(square)

print(squares_tuple)

I am trying to understand how Python will process them differently

There is no such thing as a tuple comprehension. squares_tuple is still a generator.
>>> squares_tuple = (x**2 for x in range(10))
>>> type(squares_tuple)
<class 'generator'>

Because a generator is an iterable value, you can pass it to tuple to create a tuple.
>>> tuple(squares_tuple)
(0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81)


As to why there is no tuple generator, tuples are meant to model things like C structs more than the kind of homogenous containers that lends itself to initialization via repeated function calls. At runtime, there's little difference between a tuple and a list aside from (im)mutability, but if you get into the kind of type theory that underlies static typing, then (roughly speaking) a list contains an arbitrary number of values of the same type, while a tuple contains a fixed number of values of arbitrary types.

Thanks chepner.. I'm just learning Python.. So it's a bit confusing. If I try to understand your comment, it means Lists are flexible in terms of size but rigid in terms of element types. And Tuples are rigid in terms of size but flexible in terms of element types. But I thought List can hold different data types like a list can have a int element, string element, float element etc..

That's what I meant by "at runtime". Type hints are used to impose additional strictness that is not otherwise enforced. Python doesn't care if you write x: list[int] = [1, "a", 3.14], but a type checker like mypy or pyright will. This is useful because you can get an error immediately upon assignment to x, rather than scratching your head when a later line of code like y = x[1] + 3 fails because you could have sworn x[1] should be an int.

makes some sense :)  Thanx
